# closure-library drag a goog.fx.DragListGroup Item between Panes

Tags: javascript, html, google-closure, google-closure-library

i'm currently playing with the google closure library but ran into a problem.
I try to use mulitple DragListGroups each on its own tab.
But now i want to drag and drop between these lists and tried to make it possible to drag
between the tabs.

My idea was to make the button in the tabbar droppable so i can just drag the item
to the tabbutton of the page, the page is selected and i can drop the element where i want it.

Sadly DragListGroup has no way to add targets that are not DragListGroups.

Can anyone help me here?
This is my code: http://pastebin.com/r2iywr9j
This is the css file: http://pastebin.com/EBFdNhgS

Answer (score 1):

The DragListGroup is a specialized class intended for moving list items by removing and re-inserting them. If you want to drop items on non-lists you're probably better off building on top of goog.fx.DragDrop directly instead of trying to work around its assumptions.

See the source of this demo which includes dropping list items onto buttons: http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/demos/dragdrop.html

The Closure wiki has a good overview: http://code.google.com/p/closure-library/wiki/DragDrop

Comment: I thought about that too but its lots of work to implement the sorting behaviour on top of DragDrop and i don't have a idea how to do it properly. I need to get much more familiar with the library before i can do that.